# Assigning changing numbers to a single variable

Tags: c, math, average

Just screwing around in C... wanted to make a program that calculated the average of whatever numbers the user input.

The program works fine, I just can't 'logic' out how to do the next part.

I need to be able to take each number they input and average them, using the number they input for the first scanf to divide by. I only assigned one variable for each number they input, but after about a second of looking at the code I realized I would need to use calculus or some programming trick to be able to do this (effectively) infinitely. Basically, the variable needs to change each time so the sum can be taken then divided over the total number of numbers. I'm ranting...

Can anyone who can understand my stupid problem give me some pointers? That'd be great...

My includes and the int main () are there, don't worry. Just felt no need to clutter it with already known stuff. Also, I don't do shorthand anything- I feel no need to as of now.

```
// Base variables
int iUserReq, iNumCounter = 0;
// Each individual number
double dUserNum = 0.0;
// Calculation
double dNumSum = 0.0, dNumAvg = 0.0;


// Ask user for the number of variables to be averaged... will come in handy
printf("Please input how many numbers you would like to average together, as a number. For example, 10.\nTry to keep it low, because you're going to be putting them all in manually.   >   ");
scanf("%d", &iUserReq);

// If user inputs 0 or negative number, keep asking until they put in a positive number
while(iUserReq <= 0)
{
    printf("Please input a number greater than 0.   >   ");
    scanf("%d", &iUserReq);
}

// This adds a counter, so for the number of numbers the user wants to average, it will loop that many times and ask for an input that many times
// I.e. they want to average 10 numbers, it asks for 10 numbers

// THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK... HELP?
while(iNumCounter < iUserReq)
{
    printf("Please input number.   >   ");
    scanf("%lf", &dUserNum);
    iNumCounter = iNumCounter + 1;
}

return 0;
```

Thanks...

Bagger

Comment: You've declared a variable named dNumSum.. what do you think you should do with it?

Comment: Remember that the average is the the *sum of all inputs* divided by the *number of inputs*.

Comment: following on from Joachim's comment - you can maintain the sum of the entered numbers as the user enters the numbers and then divide by the count of numbers at any point to show a running average

Comment: You should always check the return value from `scanf`. In your code, each of the calls to `scanf` should return 1, so you need to make sure that they did return 1. To see why, just type any letter, and hit the enter key.

Comment: I know how to average a sum of numbers...What I can't grasp is that the user is putting in different values for the same variable, repeatedly. How would I be able to keep a running tally of the sum as each new number is input?

Comment: Also keep in mind that the user isn't set to a specific amount of numbers to put in... it's literally their choosing, so I can't just define a constant to divide  by. The program has to be able to sum all of their inputs then divide by the number of inputs.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a *forum*, no need to mark a question as "Solved" in its title. Incidentally, you may still want to read the short introductory [tour] some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm going to bite and give you the solution.

At the top of your program:

```
double sum = 0.0;
```

After you scanf() for each number:

```
sum += dUserNum;
```

Just before `return 0`:

```
printf("%f\n", sum / iUserReq);
```

Do you understand why this works?

Comment: Don't worry, it won't be the last time something simple bites you for hours, and hours, and hours.... (that torment is spread equally among all who code)